# FFmpeg cut off video also add image over video in 1 line

Tags: ffmpeg

I need to cut off video for first 8 seconds and also add image over video to right-bottom (like logo). And I need that one in one line to not keep me waiting.

Hope you can help me, thank you already :)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Use

```
ffmpeg -ss 8 -i in.mp4 -i image.png -filter_complex overlay=W-w-10:H-h-10 out.mp4
```